# Require multiple rows from database using multiple select in php

Tags: php

I have a database witch contain users information and (with user name from database) and I have to show all information from database for user name selected.

```
<select name="user[]" id="user" multiple="multiple" tabindex="1"  onchange="showUser(this.value)">
 <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
    <?php
    foreach($result as $row){
?>
    <option value ="<?php echo $row['username']; ?>"> <?php echo $row['username'];?></option>
<?php }
?>
<?php }?>
</select>
```

I can only display data for one user even if I select two or more

edit :

this is my script function and display function:

```
<script>
function showUser(str) {
  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  } else {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","123.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
</script>
```

123.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<?php
session_start();

$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

require 'conectare.php';

mysqli_select_db($conectare,"users");
$sql = "Select * from users where username = '{$q}'";
$result = mysqli_query($conectare, $sql);


echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Username</th>
<th>Password</th>
<th>email</th>
<th>Telefon</th>
</tr>";


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['telefon'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($conectare);
?>   
</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmmjN.png)

It looks like this, I want to display 2 or more users and it only shows me one

Comment: Now is the time to do some debugging.  In your browser's debugging tools, observe the AJAX request being made.  Does it contain the data you expect?  In your server-side code, what is the runtime value of `$sql` being executed?  Is it what you expect?  (Note: Your code is *wide open* to **SQL injection**.  You'll want to correct that.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's I am trying to show how you can achieve it. To display tabular data without.
I am not answering the exact solution, because i want you learn the basics. this code
is for example only.

```
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 
//The Blank string is the password
mysql_select_db('hrmwaitrose');

$query = "SELECT * FROM employee"; //You don't need a ; like you do in SQL
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<table>"; // start a table tag in the HTML

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
  //Creates a loop to loop through     results
  echo "<tr><td>" . $row['name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['age'] . "</td></tr>";      
  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
}

echo "</table>"; 
//Close the table in HTML

mysql_close(); 
//Make sure to close out the database connection
```

Comment: I would really appreciate if you would show me the exact solution, because I really need to finish it until tomorrow. I have to use <select multiple> to chose which user information to display

Answer (score 0):

You can open your browser tools, go to network and send the request, select the **XHR** pill and observe your request in the *preview*/*response* tab of the request. Also a good practice is to use [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36366754/parameterized-queries-in-php-with-mysql-connection). This web page is actually asking for someone to perform an [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

The preview of your actual data will be really helpful in loading the page data to see what is the error that you are getting.