# Writing data to multiple tables using SQL

Tags: sql, heidisql

I would like to use 1 data entry form on my website to collect data and send this to two tables in HeidiSQL but can not work out how to do it!

**I have tried the following:**

Try 1 -

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO bookings(CustomerEmail,DJName,DatePerformance,VenueName,Town) 
    VALUES('$CustomerEmail','$DJName','$DatePerformance','$VenueName','$Town')";
        
$sql = "INSERT INTO venue(VenueName) VALUES('$VenueName')" ;
```

This did not work as the second $sql code 'canceled' out the first

Try 2 -

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO bookings(CustomerEmail,DJName,DatePerformance,VenueName,Town) VALUES('$CustomerEmail','$DJName','$DatePerformance','$VenueName','$Town')"."INSERT INTO venue(VenueName) VALUES('$VenueName')" ;
```

I tried using the . to concatenate both but this didn't work at all.

Im new to web development so have hit a wall.

Thanks

Comment: The queries look highly vulnerable to SQL injection to me - if you use PHP? If not, how is your problem related to HeidiSQL or HTML?

Comment: Why not just run each statmeent individually?  the $sql isn't being executed; you just have two strings.  Somehwere you must be executing the statements in Try 1 you need an execute after each sql statement...  (assuming you resolve the SQL injection problems  using paramaterized queries aka prepared statemnets)  (For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36366754/parameterized-queries-in-php-with-mysql-connection)  or from the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Sorry - Very new to this - I don't know what SQL injection means?

Comment: SQL injection means a user could key in a value which would corrupt your SQL statement in such a way that data could be lost, a table dropped or worse.  Using prepared statements negates this as a possibility.    For example: if you assume $VenueName has a value of `smith');drop table venue;--` what could happen to your venue table?  Moral to the story: use prepared statements.  More on it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work  Without sanatizing your data inputs from users, you run the risk of system corruption.

Comment: Questions are the begining of knowledge.  All we ask is for you to take the time, read and learn when information is presented and post what you've tried with errors and expected results a minimally complete example.  Don't be afraid to ask when you need to know more and don't let people brush you aside when you are asking a quesiton in good faith.  I'd recommend updating the ? tags to show the language you're doing this in. PhP?, .Net, Ruby on Rails? etc?

Comment: Still more reading on Prepared statements here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/230211/why-are-stored-procedures-and-prepared-statements-the-preferred-modern-methods-f and https://www.php.net/manual/it/security.database.sql-injection.php  Our goal isn't to just answer the question asked but point out vunerabilities and flaws in what is being done to help you develop a better, more robust application / design or provide alternative methods to achieve similar results.  There's more than 1 way to do something: pros/cons must be evaluated.

Comment: is there a reason not to use stored procs? https://www.heidisql.com/forum.php?t=34676